# Location of build definition in source control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using VS2012. I want to see the last modification of a build definition.
Where are the build definition stored in source control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no out off the box way to check the build definition modification history.

This is under consideration by Microsoft in visual studio uservoice

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions

you can also try some paid version here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ec36f618-d122-48a3-8236-7d9cd19791ee